# CORS error when accessing my api from my app on the same server

Tags: angular, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

I have got an Amazon EC2 Linux server with nginx.

It's got the .NET Core API as well as my Angular app.

The API configuration (from the MS doc):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name api.ZZZ.com;
    location / {
            proxy_pass              http://localhost:5000;
            proxy_http_version      1.1;
            proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header        Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header        Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass      $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

my web app configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name ZZZ.com www.ZZZ.com;
    root /var/www/ZZZ;
    server_tokens off;
    index index.html;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
    location ~* \.(png|jpg)$ {
            expires max;
            add_header Pragma Public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    }
}
```

And in the `launchSettings.json` in my API project, it's got the below snippet:

```
"iisExpress": {
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:55941"
}
```

But as per the MS doc, I have to remove `http://localhost:5001` if it is present. Apparently mine doesn't have it so I leave the above line there.

So when my website is online, I got the below CORS error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://api.ZZZ.com/YYY' from origin 'http://www.ZZZ.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

But they are not different domains! As far as I know. Please help!

Comment: `api.ZZZ.com` and `www.ZZZ.com` are different domains

Comment: @sideshowbarker I thought subdomains didn't count.

Comment: subdomains do count (downvote not from me, by the way)

Comment: @sideshowbarker thanks! Do I enable CORS in my API, in nginx or both?

Comment: CORS only needs to be enable on the `api.ZZZ.com` server

Comment: @sideshowbarker I have set up CORS there but it still doesn't work. If you get a chance, would you be able to have a look at my other post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59525060/allow-cors-on-subdomain-with-reverse-proxy-in-nginx