# allow cors on subdomain with reverse proxy in nginx

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx, cors

As per the MS doc, I need to set up a reverse proxy for my web api. The below is the nginx config with cors & reverse proxy settings:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name api.ZZZ.com;
            set $cors '';
    location / {
                            if ($http_origin ~ '^https?://(localhost|www\.ZZZ\.com|www\.ZZZ\.com|ZZZ\.com)') {
                                            set $cors 'true';
                            }

                            if ($cors = 'true') {
                                            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" always;
                                            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
                                            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
                                            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,Width,X-Requested-With' always;
                                            # required to be able to read Authorization header in frontend
                                            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Authorization' always;
                            }

                            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                                            # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
                                            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                                            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                                            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                                            return 204;
                            }
            proxy_pass              http://localhost:5000;
            proxy_http_version      1.1;
            proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header        Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header        Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass      $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            }
```

}

I also have the following in my `startup.cs`:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(corsName, builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("http://www.ZZZ.com", "http://ZZZ.com")
                       .AllowAnyHeader()
                       .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
        });
```

and later:

```
app.userCors(corsName);
```

But I am still getting the below CORS error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://api.ZZZ.com/YYY' from origin 'http://www.ZZZ.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Please help!

Comment: @sideshowbarker I have got options in the config as you can see from the code snippet. This is really making me crazy!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with `SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains` configuration and adding wildcard subdomain? like this.

In the `ConfigureServices` method.

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
        builder => builder
            .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
            .WithOrigins("https://*.example.com","https://example.com")
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowCredentials()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .Build()
        );
});
```

And in the `Configure` method

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```